# jquery find element

Tags: jquery

What is the selector I need in order to find the class "imgBtn" inside the link that I clicked (class - "checkVacancy a")?

```
      <div class="checkVacancy">
    <a rel="123">
        <img class="imgBtn" alt="" src="App_Themes/popup/bilder/btn_pruefen.png">
    </a>
    <div class="32531302a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkVacancy">
    <a rel="123">
        <img class="imgBtn" alt="" src="App_Themes/popup/bilder/btn_pruefen.png">
    </a>
    <div class="32531302b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkVacancy">
    <a rel="123">
        <img class="imgBtn" alt="" src="App_Themes/popup/bilder/btn_pruefen.png">
    </a>
    <div class="32531302c"></div>
  </div>
```

This is the JS I use

```
   $(function(){
        $('.checkVacancy a').click(function() {

          //access only child image
          $('.imgBtn').attr('src','http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/9D/E5/1C/00/00/00/1-0.gif');                  

        });
    });
```

[example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/elecaf/2/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is

```
var imgBtn = $(this).find('.imgBtn');
```

This will find the image within the link that you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
$(".checkVacancy a").click(function() {
   var theImage = $(this).find(".imgBtn"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all `imgBtn` within `a` within `checkVacancy` divs:

```
$('div.checkVacancy a .imgBtn')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you need to add "this" to your .imgBtn selector, like this:

```
$('.imgBtn', this).attr('src','http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/9D/E5/1C/00/00/00/1-0.gif');
```